# Oracle Apex 5: Using Multiple Columns in a Bar Charts Axix

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I'm trying to create a bar chart that shows the values of multiple columns from a table. It's a very simple bar chart, that I can't figure out how to design in APEX 5/SQL.

[Chart describing what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4EVA.png)

Basically, I want the X axis of the bar chart to have bar for each column of my table (that I choose), and the bar will represent the sum of that column, grouped by a column called appname.

I know I will need a:

SELECT SUM(columns)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY appname

But I can't seem to get the bar chart to represent each column I choose.

Hopefully I've explained this well, my colleagues who don't know how to help say I don't explain things well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done, but as far as I'm aware only for a fixed number of sets of data.  This is what I was able to do with some dummy data:
[image]

What you have to do is first create a chart for one of the sets something like:

```
select code, sum(value) as total
  from data
 where app_id = 1
 group by code
 order by code
```

That produces this (with my sample data):
[image]

Now when you look at the region definition you will see that the region contains a single "series":[image]

(By default it is named "Series 1" - but I already renamed mine to "App 1").

Now you can right-click on Series 1 and select "Duplicate" and a new, duplicate series will be created.  You can then edit the name and SQL of this new series to refer to application 2.  Then when you run that you will see the result I showed at the beginning.

Comment: Thank you! This has done exactly what I wanted! I was unaware of the ability to duplicate the series.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you need to do. In the chart source SQL, define something like this

```
SELECT SUM(column1) as col_sum,
       Column1 as Series,
       column1 as Column_name
       FROM myTable GROUP BY appname
       sort by appname

union all

SELECT SUM(column2) as col_sum,
       Column2 as Series,
       column3 as Column_name
       FROM myTable GROUP BY appname
       sort by appname

union all

SELECT SUM(column3) as Col1_sum,
       Column3 as Series,
       column3 as Column_name
       FROM myTable GROUP BY appname
       sort by appname
```

------ and so on - for all the columns----- 
In the Series properties, set Sources > Type as Region Source.

In Column Mappin, select Series as Series Name, Column_name as Label, and col_sum as value.

In the chart attributes, Appearance > Stack - set to No.

This should work.

Alternatively, instead of using `union all` you can also define separate SQL query for each series, and have one series per column. In that case, you will not require `Series` in your query.